# What is the path to the 'mate' executable in TextMate 2's app bundle?

Tags: macos, textmate-2

On a fresh installation of TextMate 2 the `mate` command will not install.

The *TextMate > Preferences > Terminal > Install* button does nothing.

Am I correct in assuming that the mate executable should be somewhere in the app bundle? I think it used to be `TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate`.

I have tried downloading several prebuilt binaries and each fails the same way.

Comment: Have you tried running "locate mate.app" in the terminal?

Comment: The 'mate' executable is not likely to have a .app extension, as that is a designation for an application bundle, as far as I know. You can look an /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/PrivilegedTool to see an example of an executable that has no extension. Locate mate does not find the file I am trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

To search for the file, use the following command.

```
find /Applications/Textmate2.app -name "mate"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should indeed be in `/Applications/TextMate2.app/Contents/Resources/mate`
Got my binary from here: https://github.com/textmate/textmate